# Randomize data to send as a request body in Jmeter depending on another set of random data

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I'm new at scripting in Jmeter and I've tried some functions. What I'm trying to do here is:

I have a POST request with a customer id as a path variable but I'm randomizing it:

```
http://endpoint/customers/${__RandomFromMultipleVars(customerId1|customerId2|customerId3, customer_id)}/verify
```

The line above works, and it is getting a random value among the three customer IDs, the request can result to this:

```
http://endpoint/customers/6fb5ef21-6b3e-4564-952f-e83df63a9907/verify
```

customerId1, customerId2, and customerId3 came from the config element: User Define Variables

Now, in the response body, I have this groovy script instead of an actual JSON request body:

```
${__groovy(
    if ("${customer_id}" == "6fb5ef21-6b3e-4564-952f-e83df63a9907") {

    } else if ("${customer_id}" == "8f0b21e5-ddf6-42d4-b07e-6da09db6a611") {

    } else if ("${customer_id}" == "40aa4f1b-424b-40d2-8213-36a39f5c98b2") {

)}
```

My question is I don't know if it is possible, but for every if statement, I want to randomize again the request body depending on the customer Id that was set.

I've tried doing:

```
if ("${customer_id}" == "6fb5ef21-6b3e-4564-952f-e83df63a9907") {
    ${__RandomFromMultipleVars(resp1|resp2|resp3)}          
}
```

But it resulted to an error. I've tried just returning a simple string:

```
if ("${customer_id}" == "6fb5ef21-6b3e-4564-952f-e83df63a9907") {
   "TEST"       
}
```

And it works, the string "TEST" was used as the request body. I'm really not sure on how to move forward with this. I appreciate any comments or suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> JMeter processes function and variable references before passing the script field to the interpreter, so the references will only be resolved once. Variable and function references in script files will be passed verbatim to the interpreter, which is likely to cause a syntax error. In order to use runtime variables, please use the appropriate props methods, e.g.
>
> ```
> props.get("START.HMS");
>
> props.put("PROP1","1234");
> ```

So remember that you **should not inline [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts**. Instead of accessing variables like `${customer_id}` you should be using **vars** shorthand instead, it stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance.

If you want to proceed with [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) the syntax you're looking for should be something like:

```
${__groovy(if (vars.get('customer_id').equals('6fb5ef21-6b3e-4564-952f-e83df63a9907')) { return vars.get('resp' + org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1\, 4))},)}
```

Demo:

- Variables defined at Test Plan level

  [image]
- Groovy script in action:

  [image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you so much! The script works on my side!

Noted, on the first part, I will try to learn this more. Just a follow up question:

This code here: 
   ` org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1\, 4)`
What is the '\' for?

Comment: It is needed to escape the comma which is used as parameters delimiter in JMeter Functions

Comment: Noted, and thank you! Before posting this question I've tried using 'vars' but I'm not sure on how to use it properly and I keep getting errors. Thank you also for showing how to use vars :)